# Convert pdf to image with imagemagick and get the list of outputted files

Tags: imagemagick

I found how to convert my pdf into png files with the `convert` command. It is great because out of the box it creates an image for each pages in the pdf which is exacly what I need. The thing is I don't know in advance how many pages my pdf has, so I don't know how many pages `convert` has created. I looked and looked on the Internet and read the imagemagick site but could not find an appropriate way to output the information I need.

I need a very simple output, something like this:

```
$ convert in.pdf out.png
out-0.png
out-1.png
out-2.png
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, just do:

```
identify in.pdf

in.pdf[0] PDF 256x256 256x256+0+0 16-bit sRGB 139350B 0.000u 0:00.002
in.pdf[1] PDF 256x256 256x256+0+0 16-bit sRGB 139350B 0.010u 0:00.001
in.pdf[2] PDF 256x256 256x256+0+0 16-bit sRGB 139350B 0.010u 0:00.000
```

or if you only want the names, then

```
identify -format "%f[%p]\n" in.pdf

in.pdf[0]
in.pdf[1]
in.pdf[2]
```

or if you just want to know the number of pages:

```
identify -format "%n\n" in.pdf | head -n 1

3
```

*Note without the pipe to head, you will get 3 repeated 3 times*

See

https://imagemagick.org/script/identify.php

https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer - my browser must have cached the page! Anyway, *"Merry Christmas"* to you!

Comment: No problem, Mark. The same back to you and have a Happy New Year, also.

Comment: Thank you @fmw42 . The draw back to your solution is I have to make a second command. It will do for now. It is strange that the `convert` command can't output the name of the files that itself creates!

Comment: `@Guillaume Bois` I do not understand your comment. What is it exactly that you want to do? ImageMagick can output the input name if you want using -set filename. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_convert. But what does that have to do with knowing the number of output images?

Comment: @fmw42 see my question for what I need, it is pretty clear. The `-set filename` seems to modify the output filenames. I don't need that. The default output file names is ok for me. I just need the `convert` command to output what it creates so I can process the output and, lets says, insert all N files in the database. If I don't get that, I have to revert to your solution and check with `identify` how many pages there is in the pdf files THEN use `convert` to create the N files and _assume_ everything went as planned...

Comment: convert will create separate output files automatically adding -0, -1, ... -N for all the pages of the pdf. `convert image.pdf image.png`. If it does not, then you have a bug or bad install somewhere. You can also do `convert image.png image_%02d.png` to get underscores and leading zeros.